# python in notepad++ no such file or directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, path, notepad++

python 2.7. Notepad++. Windows 10
I'm trying to open file like this:

```
sourcefile=raw_input('name of the file: ')
fhand=open(sourcefile,'r')
```

And it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Denis\Desktop\prog\python\es.py", line 135, in <module>
    fhand=open(sourcefile)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '20.04.2016.csv'
```

In notepad++ i run this: C:\Python27\python.exe -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
Kinda new to programming but i'm guesing that I have to specify somehow path to the place where my es.py and my file is. I thought $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH) does it.

If i run my code with python or idle it works fine. 
I've tried to run this program in Atom, gives same mistake. No mistakes so long as I don't work with files.

Comment: You need to execute the script in the file folder, or to provide the absolute path to the file in your script.

Comment: I know and try to do it. I've opened .py file in notepad in folder the .py is in.